# Cannot access Categories in dashboard (Magento)

Tags: php, magento

So i have installed couple of extensions one of them was fontis feed generator, everything is working fine till i try and access Manage Categories the it comes up with "There has been an error processing your request"
The error is as follows

```
a:5:{i:0;s:110:"Source model "feedsgenerator/googleproducts_source_taxonomy" not found              for attribute "google_product_category"";i:1;s:4101:"#0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this sql code to check if there's the attribute causing issues:

```
select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code = "google_product_category";
```

If you'll get a result showing the attribute then you should remove it. To do this you can do the following:
Add this to the end of your index.php file:

```
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_category','google_product_category');
```

Run the website once with disabled cache (make sure the code run) and then remove the two lines from index.php.

This should be fixed now. You can check if the attribute still exists by running the sql code again:

```
select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code = "google_product_category";
```

Comment: Thank you! I got rid of the extension at the time and that fixed the issue